# How to Implement login form and main form without more instances in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, authentication

Iam creating an instance to the main form on login button click and again creating instance to login form on logout button click. my code is

```
      if ((txtUsrNm.Text == "Admin") && (txtPswd.Text == "Admin"))
        {
            mainForm mainFm = new mainForm();
            mainFm.userNam = txtUsrNm.Text;
            mainFm.pasWrd = txtPswd.Text;
            mainFm.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }
         else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid Username or Password.");
        }
```

and again in logout button

```
        this.Hide();
        loginFrm lgn = new loginFrm();
        lgn.Show();
```

If I try to close instead of Hide, the whole application is closing.
By doing this Application.OpenForms count is increasing on every login and logout operations. How to implement the login and logout operations in windows application. Is there any other Idea for Implementing this operation. Thanking you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put your login part in Program.cs , before Application.Run() called
e.g :

```
 if (new frmLogin().ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
 {
     Application.Run(new frmMain());
 }
```

then put login codes in login form. after user logged in, form login will be closed and will set this.dialogresualt = dialogresult.ok;
e.g :

```
if (txtUserName.Text == "blah"
      && txtPassword.Text == "blah")
   {
     txtPassword.BackColor = Color.YellowGreen;
     txtUserName.BackColor = Color.YellowGreen;
     this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
   }
   else
   {
     txtPassword.BackColor = Color.Salmon;
     txtUserName.BackColor = Color.Salmon;
    }
```

Comment: I have created a property in the mainform . now Iam trying to sent txtUsername value to that property. In your way, the txtUsername value is not transfering to mainform. How to send the txtUsername value to main form

Comment: There are a lot of variable-passing-ways out there! one of the easiest is to passing value by constructor. please have a search about that. It's easier than I say. You may want to look at this as well: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14686/C-Parameter-Pass-object-by-value-The-copy-construc